# Embedding a video to HTML that does not have the .mp4 filename extension

Tags: html5-video, file-extension, mpeg-4, video-embedding

I changed the filename extension of my videos on the server from `.mp4` to `.zip`. Now I want to embed the videos in my HTML web page, but it doesn't work due to the filename extension. I'm looking for a way to tell my front-end how to interpret the embedded file and read it as MPEG-4.

Comment: How does your HTML look like now? Do you have a sample URI to a video which fails to render when embedded in your HTML?

Answer (score -1):

Why did you change the .mp4 to .zip?  Video has pretty good compression already, and making it a zip file is unlikely to save you much (if any) in terms of the size of the object.

Comment: I change the filename extension not for the sake of compression, i did that to make it unplayable for others, so that if people got the link, and they try to embed it, it won't work, and not necessarily a .zip, any filename extension that's not playable is accepted. if you have an alternative, like changing decoding/re-encoding for example or something like that, please, I'll be happy to hear you.

Comment: I gues the issue you have is the issue you wanted to give to the others...  I work for API.video, and we have a concept of 'private videos' where videos can only be viewed once - because there is a one use token in the url: for you customer - it works fine, but if they share - it does not. You might also look at video DRM.

Comment: This is no answer. Also it is misunderstanding OP: renaming a file doesn't "change" it.

Comment: But just in the way that making the video .zip prevents "other users" from playing the video, they are also preventing the browser from playing the video.  Anything the OP does in JS to change the name and make it playable could be done by "others" to watch the video as well.